# Issues with radio button in laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to set the radio button in the form using controller
( note: no database included).
 And i even have no idea how to set the radio 
button in the form using controller .
{this is my radio button}

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-25">
             <label for="gender">Gender</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-75">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" > Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
     </div>
     </div>
```

this is my controller :

```
class NewController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $fullname='sagar basnet';
        $subject='this is my test form';
         return view('newfile/forms')
            ->withFullname($fullname)
            ->withSubject($subject);

    }
```

Comment: You have to provide us code, which you have tried already

Comment: please give the details that exactly you want to do..

Comment: i want to fill up the form in view passing data form controller

Answer (score 0):

I am going make a best effort to answer your question as their is no sample code provided.

I am assuming that you want to set the state of a radio button in the UI based on conditions that occur within your controller logic.

In your controller..

```
$radioVal = false;
if ($condition) {
    $radioVal = 'checked';
}

return view('your.view', [
    'radioVal' = $radioVal;
]);
```

The condition is the condition that determines whether or not your radio is checked (e.g. apples = fruit)...

In your view...

```
<input type="radio" {{ $radioVal or 'checked' }} />
```

The "or" keyword in blade offers you a ternary shorthand alternative.

You will need to give your radio button a name obviously...

Comment: i tried this, but i am afraid its not working, here is my code :
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-25">
<label for="gender">Gender</label>
</div>
<div class="col-75">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" > Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
</div>
</div>{this is my radio button}
class NewController extends Controller
{
public function index(Request $request) {
$fullname='sagar basnet';
$subject='this is my test form';
 return view('newfile/forms')
  ->withFullname($fullname)
  ->withSubject($subject);
  }  - this is my controller